# Disable windows phone 7 hardware keys in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there any way of disabling the hardware keys on Windows Phone 7 programmatically using Silverlight?

Thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to do so, only what you can do is to override OnBackKeyPress event handler, but your **app will not pass the certification**.

Why would you like to do it anyway?

Comment: Indeed even changing the behaviour of the Back key to either previous page or dismiss popup dialog will result in failing application ingestion.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling of all hardware keys with the exception of the back key is not possible.

The back key may only be overriden for the purpose of making custom page handling mechanics properly take the user back to the previous page they were looking at when the back key is pressed.

If you're back key does not implement back key functionality you risk having your submission to the marketplace fail.